# How to use ValueResolver in another ValueResolver or chain ValueResolver with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, resolver, symfony6

I'm using Symfony 6.2 with php 8.1.

Since the update of SF 6.2 i had to remove `SensioFrameworkExtraBundle` and migrate my code from `ParamConverter` to new custom `ValueResolver`.

However, i'm facing a lack a feature from this migration or i miss something :(

With a custom `ParamConverter`, i could resolve a parameter and rewrite the new content in the `Request`. This allow me to chain any `ParamConverter`.
The new way with `custom ValueResolver` does not rewrite the content in the Request.
Of course i can force to rewrite the content or create a new attribute in the `Request` but i feel it's wrong or not proper way.

My use case :

The resolver for TranslationKey need the resolver result of TranslationDomain and TranslationLanguage.
basically i would like to chain these resolver or group them like we can do in form Constraint.

services.yaml

```yaml
App\Service\\ranslation\Request\ValueResolver\TranslationLanguageValueResolver:  
  tags:  
    - { name: controller.argument_value_resolver, priority: 103 }  
  
App\Service\Translation\Request\ValueResolver\\TranslationDomainValueResolver:  
  tags:  
    - { name: controller.argument_value_resolver, priority: 102 }  
  
App\Service\Translation\Request\ValueResolver\TranslationKeyValueResolver:  
  tags:  
    - { name: controller.argument_value_resolver, priority: 101 }
```

My controller :

```php
public function edit (Request             $request,  
   TranslationLanguage $translationLanguage,  
   TranslationDomain   $translationDomain,  
   TranslationKey      $translationKey,  
   TranslationHelper   $translationHelper,  
   Translation         $translation): Response
{
    [some code]
}
```

TranslationKeyValueResolver :

```php
public function resolve (Request $request, ArgumentMetadata $argument): iterable  
{  
    $argumentType = $argument->getType();  
 if (!$argumentType || !($argumentType === TranslationKey::class)) {  
        return [];  
   }  
  
   $translationLanguage = $request->get('translationLanguage'); //=> does not return the object since it's not chained
    [some code]
    
    return [new TranslationKey($translationKey)];
}
```

Before :

```php
    public function apply(Request $request, ParamConverter $configuration)
    {
        [some code]

        $request->attributes->set($configuration->getName(), new TranslationLanguage($languages));

        return true;
    }
```

After :

```php
public function resolve (Request $request, ArgumentMetadata $argument): iterable  
{  
    $argumentType = $argument->getType();  
 if (!$argumentType || !($argumentType === TranslationLanguage::class)) {  
        return [];  
   }  
  
    [some code]
  
 return [new TranslationLanguage($languages)];
}
```

So, i tried to create a new attribute in Request with the new value, but it feel terribly wrong since it suppose all resolver has been executed before and in order. But it's working.

I though to revolve again TranslationLangage and TranslationDomain in TranslationKeyValueResolver but i don't know how, neither what tag i should set in that case ? Custom tag ?

```yaml
App\Service\Translation\Request\ValueResolver\TranslationKeyValueResolver:  
  tags:  
    - { name: controller.argument_value_resolver, priority: 101 }
    - { name: another_tag_to_resolve_argument_from_resolver, priority: 101 } ??
```

Any idea please ?

Radyium
Thanks

Comment: got stock on the same thing. This concept seems to be missing in the implementation from symfony.